# Merge multiple arrays using zip

Tags: ruby, arrays

This may be a silly one. But I am not able to figure it out.

```
names = ['Fred', 'John', 'Mark']

age = [27, 40, 25]

location = ['Sweden', 'Denmark', 'Poland']

names.zip(age) 

#Outputs => [["Fred", 27], ["John", 40], ["Mark", 25]]
```

But I need to output it with the 3rd array (`location`) with it.

```
#Expected Output => [["Fred", 27,"Sweden"], ["John", 40,"Denmark"], ["Mark", 25,"Poland"]]
```

The most important condition here is that, there may be *any number of arrays* but the output should form from the first element of each array and encapsulate inside another array.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing multiple arguments to [`zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-zip):

```
names.zip(age, location)
# => [["Fred", 27, "Sweden"], ["John", 40, "Denmark"], ["Mark", 25, "Poland"]]
```